# Query Mongoid for all circle areas that include a given point

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Let say I have two classes:

```
class Cirle
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :lat, type: Float
  field :lon, type: Float
  field :radius, type: Integer

end


class Point
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :lat, type: Float
  field :lon, type: Float
end
```

How can I find all Circles that include a given Point?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Mongoid`, but perhaps the following will help. Suppose:

```
circles = [
  { x: 1, y: 2, radius: 3 },
  { x: 3, y: 1, radius: 2 },
  { x: 2, y: 2, radius: 4 },
]
```

and

```
point = { x: 4.5, y: 1 }
```

then the circles containing `point` are obtained with the help of [Math::hypot](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Math.html#method-c-hypot):

```
circles.select { |c|
  Math.hypot((c[:x]-point[:x]).abs, (c[:y]-point[:y]).abs) <= c[:radius] }
  #=> [{ x: 3, y: 1, radius: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 2, radius: 4 }]
```

Edit: to improve efficiency as @Drenmi suggests:

```
x, y = point.values_at(:x, :y)
circles.select do |c|
  d0, d1, r = (c[:x]-x).abs, (c[:y]-y).abs, c[:radius]
  d0*d0 + d1*d1 <= r*r
end
```

Comment: Note that `Math.hypot` uses a square root operation, which makes it considerably slower (by a factor of 2, according to `benchmark-ips`) than just comparing the squared values directly, which could be relevant for a large number of points or and circles.

Comment: @Drenmi, that's a very good point. You might be able to speed it even more (but certainly not too the same degree as dropping the square root) by first checking to see if the point is within a square with sides `2*radius` (no multiplications), avoiding the need to compute the sum of sqares if it is not. Want to add that to your benchmark?

Comment: I could add that, but it would be subject to the distribution of points in the benchmark. For a sample where a lot of the points lie outside such a square, the improvement of a 2-pass approach should be considerable. For a sample where most of them lie inside, there should instead be a small performance hit.

Comment: No. I'm not looking how to calculate it when I have an array, but how to query the database to get correct results.

Comment: Ben, you're talking to yourself again.